# i get the message "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." after second time of running

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview

hvae very spcieal problem, i read all the post on multithreading in android, but still go the famuse error. but, i got in after the second run of the same thread for exmaple "thGetDevice" from the sourcecode;

hope u can help me.. thnx..

Im get
    /** Variable definition*/
    CheckBox cbBlueTooth;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
    ListView MainListView;
    ProgressBar prProgressbar;
    Thread thGetDevices;
    Thread thClearDevices;
    Handler handler;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Initial Handler */
    handler=new Handler() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {

                /******************************
                 * 
                 * this line cuse to the trouble
                 */

                BlueQuickActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        prProgressbar.incrementProgressBy(msg.arg1);
                        mArrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)msg.obj;
                        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
                    }
                });
        }
      };


    /* Set Finalization true */
   // System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /* ListView Definition */
    TextView tvHeader = new TextView(this);
    MainListView =  this.getListView();
    MainListView.addHeaderView(tvHeader);
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    //mArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    prProgressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);


    /* Get Bluetooth driver */
    cbBlueTooth = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbTurnBlueTooth);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    /* initializing Bluetooth adapter **/
    mBluetoothAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        /*ShowNotifMessage("Sorry..", "You Don't have Bluetooth Driver");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    }

    // Initial the thGetDeviceThread and thClearDevices
    //initGetDevicesThread();
    //initClearDevicesThread();

    /*Listener for Checkbox*/
    cbBlueTooth.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (isChecked && !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                 prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                 buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                 BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
                 initGetDevicesThread();
                 buttonView.setEnabled(true);
                }
             else if (!isChecked && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                 prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                 buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                 BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().disable();
                 initClearDevicesThread();  
                 buttonView.setEnabled(true);
                }
             else
             {
                 prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                 buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                 BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
                 initGetDevicesThread();
                 buttonView.setEnabled(true);
             }
        }
    });
}

/** Gets all paird devices and put them in the Listview */
private void initGetDevicesThread()
{
 thGetDevices = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
            msg.what = 1;
            msg.obj = getDeviceList();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    });

 (thGetDevices).start();

}

/** clear all paird devices and put them in the Listview */
private void initClearDevicesThread()
{
 thClearDevices = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
            msg.what = 2;
            msg.obj = clearListOfDevices();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    });

 (thClearDevices).start();

}

public ArrayAdapter<String> getDeviceList()
{
    while(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON);
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName());
        }
    }

    return mArrayAdapter;
}

private ArrayAdapter<String> clearListOfDevices()
{
    while(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF);
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainListView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    return mArrayAdapter;
}



//** */
private void ShowNotifMessage(String strTitle,String strMsg)
{
    dialog.setTitle(strTitle);
    dialog.setMessage(strMsg);
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You cannot Update the UI from a non-UI Thread. To do so you have to use `runOnUiThread()`. Put your code to update the UI inside the `runOnUiThread()`.

```
Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                prProgressbar.incrementProgressBy(msg.arg1);
        mArrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)msg.obj;
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        prProgressbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    }
        });
```

Comment: the handler supose to send the message to the UIthread throw the queue.

Comment: yes but you are trying to update the UI from a non UI thread by setting the adapter for the List setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
. That can only be done from the UI thread. So for that you need to put that part inside the runOnUIThread().

Comment: not working... 'code'              BlueQuickActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      
      public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
      }
     });'code' thanks any way

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: 11-12 14:36:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(21408): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. but only in the scond time that the thead is called...

Comment: check my updated answer and keep everything inside runOnUiThread().

Comment: sorry... sameproblem.. in the second run of the thread im getting the same error... i updated the mainpost for u to see the changes... thanks for ur time...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Handler like below

```
Handler viewUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                ~~~~your code~~~
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: declare it as int msgToSend = 1;